# Sorting null-data last in database query

Tags: sql, android

i have an application where i order make a query to my database with an ORDER BY clause, it will order them in alphabetical order. i only have one small problem, it happens fairly often that one of the strings that the query is ordering by contains nothing (string="") when sorting in alphabetical order these get populated at the top of the list infront om a,b,c... i plain and simple dont want this. after a lot of googling i found on an oracle forum that i should change the SORT BY part of the query to "SORT BY xxx ASC NULLS LAST" this caused a fatal error when querying.

how shall i go by fixing this seemingly small issue?

here is my query statement as is today.

`public Cursor fetchAllDatesByTag() {
return mdiktationsDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_DATEID + "," +" " + KEY_DATE + "," + " " + KEY_TIME + "," + " " + KEY_DICTTAG + "," + " " + KEY_DICTLISTIMAGE + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + KEY_DICTTAG + " ASC", null);
}`

Comment: Why concatenate the strings "," and " " when the CPU can do it for you?

Comment: Wait, do the fields contain empty strings (`""`) or actual `NULL`s?

Comment: empty strings , should have been more clear about that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a `CASE` equivalent in your `ORDER BY`

Like

```
ORDER BY CASE column WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, column
```

so then it orders by the nulls first, then the actual column.

EDIT: And if you want to filter ""s (blank strings) or whatever else, you can employ this same method... assigning a numeric value to it and sorting before the alphabetizing.

EDIT2:

```
....+ " ORDER BY CASE " + KEY_DICTTAG + "WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, " + KEY_DICTTAG + " ASC"
```

Comment: must have missunderstood how to implement, could you please make those changes in the query i posted and repost that?:) thank you!

Comment: I added more query info but it will depend on your DB... my example is for SQL Server.... another DB will have some sort of `CASE` equivalent

Comment: ok thank you! , i will look into it som more:) btw i am using sqllite database. and something i forgot to be clear about was that the strings i am sorting by are empty , so not null.

Comment: so instead of `WHEN NULL THEN` use `WHEN '' THEN`

Comment: `CASE column WHEN NULL` won't work. it is equivalent to `=NULL`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution one:**

```
ORDER BY foo NULLS LAST
```

and

```
ORDER BY foo NULLS FIRST
```

But this seems to work only with numeric columns :(

**Solution two:**

```
ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(my_field),1,0),my_field
```

which will create a "fake"-column that just consist 0 or 1, depending on if my_field is null or not null, and sort on that. the fields that are not null will come first. in a second step, SQL will sort my_field, like before.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a WHERE field IS NOT NULL.  This way you shouldn't get any null values back from your query.

Comment: I presume he wants the records where that field is null, just sorted last.

Comment: exactly, i still want to get those with null value queried as they hold other information :) just want them last and not first ^^

Comment: woops sorry.  read your question incorrectly.  I vote for Matthews answer!