# TSQL query optimizer view on non-nullable ISNULL()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

As part of some dynamic SQL (ick), I've implemented the 'sort NULLs last' solution described here: [Sorting null-data last in database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620624/sorting-null-data-last-in-database-query)

```
ORDER BY CASE column WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, column
```

My question is: On non-nullable columns that have ISNULL() applied to them, will the query optimizer strip this out when it realises that it will never apply?

Comment: Try a simple case and take a look at the Actual Execution Plan.  Should see it as a scalar operation, I think.  Then try it again without the ISNULL to compare.  My gut is that the optimiser doesn't do what you hope; why add complexity to the optimiser to undo what is at-best redundant and at worst a feck-up by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why your question mentions the [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184325.aspx) function when that isn't in your code.

```
ORDER BY CASE column WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, column
```

First of all this code doesn't work, it is equivalent to `CASE WHEN column = NULL` which is not what you need.

It would need to be

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, column
```

The optimisation question is easy to test.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
  (
     X INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  )

SELECT *
FROM   #T
ORDER BY X

SELECT *
FROM   #T
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, X 

DROP TABLE #T
```

The plan shows a sort operation in the second plan indicating that this was not optimised out as you hoped and the pattern is less efficient than `ORDER BY X`.

[image]